# WP8.1 Appbar HideCommands Issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, winjs, appbar

I am writing a WP8.1 app using WinJS and the navigation template in Visual Studio.  I have an appbar in my app and when I navigate to different pages I use hideCommands/showCommands to customize the appbar with commands that are appropriate for the page.  The issue is that the commands to be hidden are not completely hidden before the commands to be shown are shown.  This creates a momentary flash of the buttons to be hidden.

```
 var commands = [appbar.winControl.getCommandById("commandA"), appbar.winControl.getCommandById("commandB"), appbar.winControl.getCommandById("commandC")];
 appbar.winControl.hideCommands(commands);
 appbar.winControl.showCommands("commandD");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a separate command bar per page?  What happens if you disable or even hide the command bar, then add/remove your menu items, then enable and show the command bar again?

Comment: Thanks for the advice but unfortunately when I add an appbar to each page it is not visible on the page.

Comment: Hiding the appbar, adding/removing the buttons and then showing has no effect.  The buttons that should not be visible are visible for a moment before being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I used to think having only one AppBar would be better than creating one for every page so I had the same approach you did using the [showOnlyCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700574.aspx). That worked fine on Windows 8 (& 8.1) but definitely does not work as expected in WinPhone 8.1

So what I ended up doing is having my AppBar markup in every page I where needed an AppBar.

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar"></div>
```

I do have some code to show/hide commands from the AppBars using the `showOnlyCommands` method which has worked with no problems ever since.

*One tip of advice*: `showOnlyCommands` can receive an array of either the commads ID (as string) or the `AppBarCommands` themselves. I found the later worked as expected. Had a little issues with the IDs

Comment: Thanks for the advice but unfortunately when I add an appbar to each page it is not visible on the page.

Comment: that should be related to another issue (?) that approach works like a charm. Care to share some code?

Comment: <body>
    <!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
    <div class="fragment homepage">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        </section>
    </div>
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar"></div>
    </body>

Comment: But your missing the commands http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700497.aspx

Comment: I added buttons but it still doesn't appear. I'm able to get an appbar to show up on my first page but when I navigate to another page the appbar for that page seems to be hidden and when navigating back to the first page the appbar that was visible is now also hidden.

Comment: If you share a project on onedrive, dropbox or whatever I might be able to help you